# Solving the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $a_1,a_2...$ and $b_1,b_2...$ be sequences of positive real numbers such that $a_1=b_1=1$ and $b_n=b_{n-1}a_n-2$ for $n=2,3...$ Assume that the sequence $b_j$ is bounded, find $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_1a_2...a_n}$$
I tried to guess a sequence but couldn't continue like this. The biggest difficulty I'm facing is with $b_n$.

Comment: Your question does not tell us what $a_n$ is...

Comment: I have typed the complete question. According to this no data is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have;

> Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ and $b_1,b_2,\cdots$ be sequences of positive real
> numbers such that $a_1=b_1=1$ and $b_n=b_{n-1}a_n-2$ for $n=2,3,\cdots$,
> assume that the sequence $b_j$ is bounded, find $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty
>  \frac{1}{a_1a_2...a_n}$$

using the recurrence relation and substituting in S directly we get;
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty
 \frac{b_{n-1}{a_n}-b_n}{a_1a_2...a_n}$$

Partial fraction the sum and shifting the index by 1 (so we add 1 to S), we get

$$S=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{b_{n-1}}{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}} - \frac{b_n}{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}+1$$

Telescope the sum;

$$S=\frac{b_1}{2a_1}+1$$

Using $a_1=b_1=1$;

> $$S=\frac{3}{2}$$